# Integrable Business Intelligence

Tags: business-intelligence

Could you please recommend me a highly customizable and integrable BI solution? I would like to integrate it with an existing website and parametrized dashboards and analytical reports.

I suppose the solution should work like a BI server, where I can send data to the system, let it work out on its own and display the result on our website.

The application has a backend written in Java, Spring Boot, which publishes a REST API and the frontend is AngularJS, completely separate from the backend (different servers).

Features:

- Dashboard generation /at least data, maybe it is possible to integrate fully generated UI?/
- Fixed reports (installed somehow, runs a specific report generation)
- Dynamic reports: The user can set parameters for the report, like "only allow include from Previous sales data between date and date" or "Don't include Xy while generating the report". (To achieve this, I don't mind if it is done by scripting the BI Server or something similar)

Considering the price I should look at every possibility, but we would prefer something that not too "enterprise". The pricing model should be one time preferably (I saw some services and they try to charge you based on users, which is not applicable for us).

The software will be used by our close partners only (very few users, <10 at start).

Comment: Thanks! I've integrated the price part with your question and will clean up comments now. License part is still missing (I was thinking of whether you want to use it internally only, or offer it as a service for customers – in the latter case, the proposed solution's license must allow for that, e.g. "unlimited" users etc), so you might consider to add some details on that, too.

Answer (score 0):

[Syncfusion Dashboard](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/dashboard) is an end to end Dashboard and Business Intelligence solution.

Dashboards can be deployed with the dashboard server or embedded in your web application.

- Backend server: .NET based environment is needed ([details](https://help.syncfusion.com/dashboard-platform/system-requirements))
- Frontend: Can be embedded in Angular JS ([details](https://help.syncfusion.com/dashboard-platform/dashboard-sdk/getting-started/angular-2))

[image: Syncfusion Dashboard]

The Dashboard Platform available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue) and flat licensing is available even otherwise (not counting the number of users).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.